# Cellular iPad shows country code on Messages being used within the US

Tags: ipad, messages

I recently purchased a refurbished iPad Pro 10.5" with cellular (I originally ordered the WiFi-only but received the WiFi+Cellular since they no longer had the other model. Bonus!!). Everything works fine but I noticed a rather annoying problem with Messages. For context, I live in the United States.

After I transferred my apps and data, I proceeded to check my setup and settings. In Messages, all the phone numbers listed had a +82 prefix. Google shows this as a country code for South Korea. My Contacts cards all show up properly. Messages on my iPhone show up properly. When I when back to Messages on the iPad, some of the numbers now show up properly. I checked **Settings** > **General** > **Language & Region** and made sure that the **Region** is set to "United States".

It seems that contacts that I have messaged on my iPhone will have the proper number displayed. Messages that I receive still show the country code. If I send a message on the iPad, the recipient sees the +82 prefix in front of my number. I don't care about getting a SIM card to enable the cellular features.

I mostly text via my phone or MacBook Pro, so this is an annoyance rather than a hindrance. How can I get my iPad to **not** show the country code on incoming/outgoing messages?

Comment: Hmmm… sounds a little like this from this morning, though it doesn't contain enough detail to work on - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441625/siri-is-quoting-the-wrong-telephone-number-in-california